# What are some limitations of using Collaborative Deep learning for Recommender systems?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, recommender-system

Recently I worked on a paper by Hao Wang, [Collaborative Deep learning for Recommender Systems](http://www.wanghao.in/paper/KDD15_CDL.pdf); which uses a two way tightly coupled method, Collaborative filtering for Item correlation and Stacked Denoising Autoencoders for the Optimization of the problem.

I want to know the limitations of using stacked Autoencoders and Hierarchical Bayesian methods to Recommender systems.